# java code errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i have a simple code in java but i can't solve some errors.
errors are:

1)illegal start of expression
2)";" expected
the errors are all found in lines *

```
public class Exer5 {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        float dieresi;
        int pollaplasiasmos;
        int prosthesi;
        int aferesi;

        num1=10;
        num2=6;


    *public void prosthesi(int num1,int num2) {
        prosthesi = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("To apotelesma tis prosthesis einai:"+prosthesi);
    }

    *public void aferesi() {
        aferesi = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("To apotelesma tis aferesis einai:"+aferesi);
    }

    *public void dieresi() {
        dieresi = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println("To apotelesma tis dieresis einai:"+dieresi);
    }

    *public void pollaplasiasmos() {
        pollaplasiasmos = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println("To apotelesma tou pollaplasiasmou einai:"+pollaplasiasmos);
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: You did not close your main method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's your original code, you are not closing the `main` function. You are missing a `}` right before `public void prosthesi(int num1,int num2)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to close your main method with a }

Answer (score 3):

I see several issues here:

1. the main methods closing `}` is at the end of the class (it's not missing).
2. the variables defined in `main...` are not visible to the other methods, you should define instance attributes (see example below)
3. the main method is static whereas all other methods are non-static

I recommend to have a look at the [basic concepts of Java's implementation of object-orientation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). A simplified *object-oriented* solution may look like this (removed some code):

```
public class Exer5 {
    int prosthesi; // for your next exercise, mark this private

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // attribute prosthesi is *not visible* to main

        int num1=10;
        int num2=6;

        // create the object and send a message to it
        Exer5 e5 = new Exer5();
        e5.prosthesi(num1, num2);
    }

    public void prosthesi(int num1,int num2) {
        this.prosthesi = num1 + num2; // assign result to instance attribute
        System.out.println("To apotelesma tis prosthesis einai:" + prosthesi);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing bracket on your main method. That should be it!